# WCF serializing struct of Array of Classes

Tags: arrays, vb.net, wcf, serialization

I have something similar to the flowing two simple classes:

```
<DataContract> _
Public Class C1
    Public Sub New(x_ As Int64)
        _x= x_
    End Sub
    <DataMember()> _
    Public Property x As Int64
End Class

<DataContract> _
Public Class C2
    Public Sub New(y_ As string)
        _y= y_
    End Sub
    <DataMember()> _
    Public Property y As string
End Class
```

and the following structure that made of both:

```
<DataContract, StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential), _
 KnownType(GetType(C1)), KnownType(GetType(C2))> _
Public structure S1
    <DataMember, MessageHeaderArray> _
    Public Second() As C1
    <DataMember> _
    Public First As C2
End structure
```

Finally, I'm calling a sub from a server's interface that sends an array of those structures as follows:

```
<ServiceContract(CallbackContract:=GetType(IClient))> _
Public Interface IServer
    <OperationContract> _
    Sub SendToServer(ByVal S()As S1)
End Interface
```

The problem is when I'm trying to pass this using WCF I'm getting a strange exception of the following format:

> The use of type 'S1' as a get-only collection is not supported with NetDataContractSerializer.  Consider marking the type with the CollectionDataContractAttribute attribute or the SerializableAttribute attribute or adding a setter to the property.

I tried to use the two suggested attributes, but I found that they should be used on declaring new class  collection of types `public class xx(Of T)`, not for my case (an exception telling that when used), I really can't understand about which get-only property he speaking about, because I have none, anyway, removing `Public Second() As C1` from the structure, or passing one instance of the structure instance of an array, fixes the problem.

So I tried to change S1 to a class instead of structure, and the array into a List with get & set parts, but nothing helps, any clue what is going here?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you are using NetDataContractSerializer? Unless you are trying to support some legacy code, I believe you should use DataContractSerializer.